# Android studio, Firebase database, exchange value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to exchange value (in the same child) in my firebase database.
In my firebase I have v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5, and when i click on my button I want to do this:

v1=v2

v2=v3

v3=v4

v4=v5

v5 = new_value

I use this, it work perfectly, but it's too slow...

I use doTranslation in the case when 2 users click the button in the same time.

```
    tampon = new_valeur;
    acienvaleur = v5;



    refplayer.child(id_player).child("v5").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                String value = mutableData.getValue(String.class);

                if (value == null) {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                mutableData.setValue(tampon);
                tampon = acienvaleur;


                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                refplayer.child(id_player).child("v4").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        String value = mutableData.getValue(String.class);

                        if (value == null) {
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                        }

                        mutableData.setValue(tampon);
                        tampon = value;



                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        refplayer.child(id_player).child("v3").runTransaction(new 
                            Transaction.Handler() {
                            @Override
                            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                String value = mutableData.getValue(String.class);

                                if (value == null) {
                                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                }

                                mutableData.setValue(tampon);
                                tampon = value;



                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                refplayer.child(id_player).child("v2").runTransaction(new 
                                    Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) 
                                        {
                                        String value = mutableData.getValue(String.class);

                                        if (value == null) {
                                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                        }

                                        mutableData.setValue(tampon);
                                        tampon = value;



                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        refplayer.child(id_player).child("v1").runTransaction(new 
                                            Transaction.Handler() {
                                            @Override
                                            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData 
                                                mutableData) {
                                                String value = mutableData.getValue(String.class);

                                                if (value == null) {
                                                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                                }

                                                mutableData.setValue(tampon);
                                                tampon = value;



                                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, 
                                            boolean b,
                                                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
}
}
}
```

Do you have any solution to speed up my change ?
}

Json :
Before :

```
"v1" : "5",
"v2" : "12",
"v3" : "102",
"v4" : "444",
"v5" : "2",
```

After:

```
"v1" : "12",
"v2" : "102",
"v3" : "444",
"v4" : "2",
"v5" : "9999",
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the actual JSON you have *before* and *after* the transaction (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: ok, hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're modifying all the child nodes under `refplayer.child(id_player)`, things should be a lot faster if you just run a single transaction on that level.

---

```
refplayer.child(id_player).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        mutableData.child("v1").setValue(mutableData.child("v2").getValue(String.class));
        mutableData.child("v2").setValue(mutableData.child("v3").getValue(String.class));
        mutableData.child("v3").setValue(mutableData.child("v4").getValue(String.class));
        mutableData.child("v4").setValue(mutableData.child("v5").getValue(String.class));
        mutableData.child("v5").setValue(new_valeur);

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        ...
    }

 }
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but how can i do it ? Because I have to wait the succed of the first transaction to do the second, etc... Havent I?

Comment: As far as I can see there's only a single transaction going on here. If you think there's a need for running multiple transactions, **you** will have to explain why. If you're having a hard time with that, give the approach I suggest a try.

Comment: There are 5 values which are modified !! If I can make it with 1 transaction (I want a "doTransaction") tell me how please

Comment: All values are under a single common node. So if you run a transaction on that common node, you can modify them all in one go. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work... not error in these line but my whole code doens't work any more

Comment: Note that we've gone from me explaining how to make your code faster (using a single transaction handler on the parent node), to me showing you in code how to do that. You'll have to do better than "it doesn't work" at this point. If you set a breakpoint and step through the transaction handler, do all values seem to be correct? Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?